# Postgres backup as tar.gz

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to backup Postgres with pg_dump.

```
pg_dump $POSTGRES_DB -U postgres > $POSTGRES_DB-$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M).sql
```

What is the way to backup it as tar.gz?

Answer (score 10):

Some options:

```
---Custom format which is compressed
pg_dump -Fc $POSTGRES_DB -U postgres > $POSTGRES_DB-$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M).out

---Postgres tar format compressed with gzip
---This will need to be uncompressed first then fed to pg_restore as 
---pg_restore does not understand compressed tar format.
pg_dump -Ft $POSTGRES_DB -U postgres | gzip > $POSTGRES_DB-$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M).tar.gz

---Postgres plain text compressed with gzip
pg_dump $POSTGRES_DB -U postgres | gzip > $POSTGRES_DB-$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M).tar.gz

---Alternate plain text compression where -Z is the level of compression(0..9). 
pg_dump $POSTGRES_DB -U postgres -Z 5 > $POSTGRES_DB-$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M).gz
```

For more detail on what the options mean see [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). The `-Fc` option is probably the most useful, in my opinion, as it allows you more options on what to restore. You can restore everything or portions using the options shown here [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).